auto-complete etc support for protobuf generated code
I filed this issue under bazelbuild, but now think it's likely more of a py_proto_library issue.
In particular, this bug mentions
"There is an option --pyi_outin protoc 21.5 which does what mypy-protobuf does without installing another dependency"
Is --pyi_out possible with py_proto_library?
